# ampersand the manifest file (intent filter)

Tags: android, xml

I need to put a url in the android:host and it contains & what can I do for it

```
 <data android:scheme="http" android:host="www.xxxxxx.c93e7ef8c2043cd7&f" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the html entity that stands for an ampersand sign:

```
&amp;
```

Comment: @MichaelP. please explain why is this low quality.

Comment: just look at Guffa's answer.

Comment: Upvoted because the answer adresses OP's exact question.

Answer (score 5):

Use the [XML entity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references) `&amp;` for the `&` character:

```
<data android:scheme="http" android:host="www.xxxxxx.c93e7ef8c2043cd7&amp;f" />
```